# What is the "total function"?

Tags: c

In the "JPL Institutional Coding Standard for the C programming Language", I found following sentence just below the Rule 15 (page 14):

"This is consistent with the principle that the use of **total functions** is preferable over **non-total functions**.".

I haven't heard the "total functions" before. What is this? Could you give me some example of the total function?

Below is the link to the JPL document.

http://lars-lab.jpl.nasa.gov/JPL_Coding_Standard_C.pdf

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Total_function) might help.

Comment: I believe the sentence following that one defines it: *A **total function** is setup to handle all possible input values, not just those parameter values that are expected when the software functions normally.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read the next sentence but I couldn't get the meaning clearly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's explained in the next sentence in the document:

> A total function is setup to handle all possible input values, not 
>   just those parameter values that are expected when the software
>   functions normally.

I think it's originally a mathematical term. A *total function* is one that has well defined behavior for all possible argument values.

An example of a non-total function is `strlen()`, which has undefined behavior if its argument is a null pointer, or an invalid pointer, or a pointer into an array that has no null `'\0'` character. (And there's no real way, at least in portable C, to make `strlen()` detect and handle all possible invalid arguments.)

A *total* function, in the sense used in the document either returns a meaningful result for all possible inputs, or detects any invalid inputs and reports an error in some well defined manner.

Comment: Does a JPL document really use "setup" as a verb?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I understand the meaning of the total function. Information about background (mathematical term) is also helpful to understand. Also I appreciate the example.

Comment: Sigh.  I'll bet they do that "alot" now.

Answer (score 1):

A total function is a function that has a defined (and by implication, correct) value for every possible input value. That is, JPL is saying that it's preferable to write functions that *always* give the right answer, not ones that only give the right answer for the range of values that someone had in mind when they were writing the function.

However, if you write a function that *isn't* total (its domain of applicability is smaller than the range of its input type), you should add checks that make sure that you generate an error whenever you encounter an input value that won't give a correct output, instead of continuing with invalid state.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I can clearly understand the meaning. And I found that I should make total function for secure coding.

Comment: Maybe this is philosophical, but isn't adding checks (which should result in meaningful errors) a way to make he function total?